# How to insert a 2D attribute in a class diagram using Modelio tool?

Tags: class-diagram, modelio

I need to insert a **2D attribute** and show it as a parameter of a function in my class diagram using **Modelio tool.**

Comment: What d oyou mean by a 2D attribute? A attribute typed by a Classe named 2D ?

Comment: A 2D array! As in, variable : integer[0..n][0..n]. Why would i ask about the naming?

Answer (score 0):

In pure UML, you have to create a type intergerArray which will represent interger[0..n] then your parameter will be an array of this integerArray.

If you target a specific code implementation Java, C++ or C# Modelio, as any other tool generating code from Model, has a specific way to specify it.

You can ask it here https://www.modelio.org/forum/index.html